# displaying dynamically created radio buttons with line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have some code to dynamically create radio buttons on an html page using javascript. Where and how can I perhaps add a `"<br>"` in order to have the radio buttons display one per line on the resulting html page?
Please take a look at the jsfiddle via the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/owuqm8j8/

```js
 var radio_home = document.getElementById("radio_home");

 function makeRadioButton(options) {
     var div = document.createElement("div");
     for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
         var label = document.createElement("label");
         var radio = document.createElement("input");
         radio.type = "radio";
         radio.name = options[i].name;
         radio.value = options[i].value;
         label.appendChild(radio);
         label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[i].text));
         div.appendChild(label);
         }
       radio_home.appendChild(div);
 }
 var options = [{
     name: "first",
     value: "yes",
     text: "yes"
 }, {
     name: "first",
     value: "no",
     text: "no"
 }]
  var options2 = [{
     name: "second",
     value: "ohhh yes",
     text: "ohhh yes"
 }, {
     name: "second",
     value: "ohhh no",
     text: "ohhh no"
 }]
makeRadioButton(options);
makeRadioButton(options2);
```

```html
<div id="radio_home"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a `<br>` tag you simply use the `document.createElement` function as you did for the radioubuttons and apend it straight after

```
function makeRadioButton(options) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        var radio = document.createElement("input");
        radio.type = "radio";
        radio.name = options[i].name;
        radio.value = options[i].value;
        label.appendChild(radio);
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[i].text));
        div.appendChild(label);

        //if we are on the last itteration there is no need to create another <br>
        if(i+1<options.length)div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
    radio_home.appendChild(div);
}
```

Updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bowkvc4v/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired results, you do not even need `<br>`. Just create div inside the for loop and append it to the containing parent inside the loop only. You need to update your function to following

```
function makeRadioButton(options) {

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
     var div = document.createElement("div"); // moved inside the loop
     var label = document.createElement("label");
     var radio = document.createElement("input");
     radio.type = "radio";
     radio.name = options[i].name;
     radio.value = options[i].value;
     label.appendChild(radio);
     label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[i].text));
     div.appendChild(label);
     radio_home.appendChild(div); // moved inside the loop
  }
}
```

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/owuqm8j8/2/

Comment: when I do that, it is only returning the last option of the radio buttons. Any thoughts why that is and how to fix? In my implementation, I am returning the div at the end, so the line "radio_home.appendChild(div);" can be commented out. I am calling the function within the html file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for displaying the radio buttons one below the other, you can probably make use of the display property of css and add it to the label. Hers is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owuqm8j8/5/), code below:

```
label
{display:block;}
```